# Put asp.net code (html helpers) with a javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have a question about javascript and html helpers in asp.net, can I use javascript to fill a div with html helpers? like this:

```
   $('#example').append("@using (Html.BeginForm('Create,'Company', FormMethod.Post)"+)
                         "{"+
                                  "@Html.TextBox('Name',new {@class = 'input-class'})"+
                         "}");
```

I knew fill with append a normal html form in a div

```
$('#example').append("<form action = '/Company/Create' method = 'Post'>"+
                           "<input type = 'text' class = 'input-class'/>"+
                     "</form>")
```

but I dont know if is possible use html helpers